# Django - Child Template with Multiple Parents - Call Child from Parent

Tags: python, django, templates, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a site using Django that allows users to view the same Google map on different pages (using gmapi). I was hoping to just create one **map template** that contains the map with some surrounding markup and then be able to include this template in different parent templates (web pages.) The key is I need to be able to pass different types of content to the child (map) template.

Could anyone propose a good way to do this?

Here are the specifics:

The applications has these conceptual objects:
1) Events
2) Facilities
3) Members

When the user is on the "events" page, I would want to pass various event data points to the **map template**. When the user is on the "facilities" page, I would want to pass various facility data points to the **map template.** When the user is on the "members" page, I would want to pass various "members" data points to the **map template.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `include` template tag with parameters;

```
{% include 'map_template.html' with event_data=some_event_data facilities_data=some_facilities_data memmbers_data=some_members_data %}
```

sample `map_template.html`;

```
<div>
    {% if event_data %}
        show event data here
    {% endif %}


    {% if facilities_data%}
        show facilities data here
    {% endif %}


    {% if memmbers_data%}
        show memmbers data here
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try implementing this and will let you know how it works.